# Could not write output : Access is denied for c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

While developing an application to find system **process** details using the given code i was able to get the desired result but at the same time i could not build the code for second time.

```
var processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
{                    
var row1 = new string[] { theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.BasePriority};
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1 );
}
```

Rebuilding the solution in **admin** mode also gave me the error :

[image]

**tempcache** is the project name.

Anyone ran into same issue ? Any help ..:/

Comment: You may have such error if an instance of the exe is running when compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue that made me worry for some time.The execution files were caught by **anti-virus** program.

I **restored** the files and added to **exclusion** list.

Now ,i could easily run the application.
Hope would be helpful for some others.